# how to get fb:pages meta tag?

Tags: facebook, metadata, meta-tags

We have website that is not live yet, but we do have it's facebook account setup. Do you know how to get value fb:page meta property that looks like `<meta property="fb:pages" content="573657212813733" />`

Answer (score 2):

That meta tag needs to go in the header of your website pages. To get the `content` value you need, click **About** in the left-hand menu of your Facebook page, and scroll down to **Page ID** towards the bottom. Use that number.